# Reassigning variables in a loop in a simple TI-Basic program

Tags: ti-basic

In my notes (from late 90s!), I found a simple TI-Basic program that takes an integer N and outputs the smallest prime number larger or equal to N.

```
Prompt N
If (N/2) = int (N/2)
1+N -> N
For (I, 3, 2+iPart(√N, 2)
If (N/I) = iPart(N/I)
Then
2+N -> N
1 -> I
End
End
Disp
Stop
```

In lines 7 and 8, the author of the program (could be me, I don't remember!) reassigns the variables I and N. This happens in the For loop. I want to ask how "reassigning variables in a loop" works in the TI-Basic language or whether the author introduced a bug, made an error, or in general demonstrated bad programming style.

Allow me to describe the program as I understand it:

1. ask for an input N, assume int
2. if N is even, update N to the next odd
3. the For loop: declare a variable I which will serve as a potential divisor of N. I begins with a value of 3 since we know N is not even. I is to be incremented by 2s (so 3, 5, 7, ..., 2+int(√N)).
4. the body of the For loop is a single If-Then-End. The logic appears to go: if I is a divisor of N, then N is not prime and the current value of N should be incremented to the next odd number, otherwise continue. But herein lies the source of my confusion: why the reassignment 1 -> I? I would think the For loop construct takes care of I.

Since N and I are being reassigned during the loop, how does that affect the For loop variables with the same names? Does the value for 2+int(√N) remain the original value during the entire loop?

I am not sure whether one of the following are occuring in Ti-Basic:

```
n=3
For (i, 1, n)
"""""""""""""Does n get updated?
Disp i, n
n+1->n
End
```

sample output:

```
1, 3
2, 4
3, 5
4, 6
5, 7
6, 8
7, 9
...
```

alternatively, assuming that the For loop is reinitialized each time its end bound value is modified, sample output:

```
1, 3
1, 4
1, 5
1, 6
1, 7
1, 8
1, 9
...
```

What happens if we similarly reassign i during the loop?

Do I need to know anything about local variables and local scopes?

For this program to work mathematically, I think the For loop needs to restart each time N is found to have a proper divisor. But that does not appear to be happening in the program, or is it?

I tried installing an emulator without success. I do not own a TI calculator any longer. I realize that there are several TI-Basic languages (to my knowledge, TI-83's version lacked local variables among other things). If the answer to my question depends on the TI-Basic, then I don't know what else to say.

Answer (score 2):

Storing a value to the variable used as loop counter is allowed, it can be used to re-start the loop like this for example. Setting `I` to 1 means (thanks to the addition done by the `For(`, with a step of 2) that the next iteration has `I=3`, so this is OK.

Storing a new value to a variable used as (or *in*, a loop bound can be a complex expression) a loop bound is also allowed, but the loop bounds are not re-evaluated during the loop so it has no effect on the looping. So in this program, the loop bound does not actually go up, though it does seem to rely on that. But I could not find any example of it actually going wrong. What I think would have to happens here is that, thanks to the `2+`, it would require a prime gap with *two* squares in it (so the integer part of square root can go up by 2 and we don't encounter a prime in the meantime) and then the second square could be misidentified as a prime (if it is the square of a prime). There is [a conjecture](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s000130050469) that this situation does not happen - while unproven, that there has been no disproof means that the lowest example would be quite out of reach for a TI-BASIC program anyway. I don't expect the author had this in mind..

There are no local variables in TI-BASIC, and nothing like lexical scoping. The variables used in programs are the same variables that the user can manipulate from the home screen (and other applicable places), and shared by other programs.

Comment: I've updated the post because I felt my original wording was unclear. Thank you for the reply, you've cleared up a few issues., You're right about the prime gaps and since, as you say, the end loop bound is not re-evaluated, that puts N to rest for me, leaving me only with worrying about what happens to I during iteration. :)

Answer (score 0):

with slight edits(the program looks like this)

```
    Input N
    If (N/2)=int(N/2)
    1+N→N
    For(I,3,2+iPart(√(N)),2)
    If (N/I)=iPart(N/I)
    Then
    2+N→N
    1→I
    End
    End
    Disp N
```

it works.
the short answer is that in ti-basic, the end command is staying that this is the end of the block of code. It can be interpreted as

````
    Input N
    If (N/2)=int(N/2)
    1+N→N
    For(I,3,2+i```Part(√(N)),2)
        If (N/I)=iPart(N/I):Then
            2+N→N
            1→I
    Disp N
````

is that helpful?

Comment: the indentation can be helpful for some, I could parse the code without the need to indent. What would be really helpful, is if I could understand (1) why the assignment 1->I is necessary in the loop (2) how it affects the For loop variable I.

Comment: @sasha the call to set I to one I do not believe is necessary. there is no class variables or anything, everything is global. that makes the for loop variable I 1. it doesn't look like it does anything though. 2 and 3 output 5 though.